# How to deploy an automl model from gcp as a web app using streamlit on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, streamlit, automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I plan to build an application which asks user input in the form of news and predicts it as fake or true.
i have trained the model using automl google cloud platform (GCP) on vertex AI platform. I have created the endpoint.

How to proceed further? How to build an app without downloading anything on local system? (all of this should be built on GCP)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the endpoint created on Google Vertex AI. I am now able to get live predictions using that endpoint but in JSON format, I just wanted to make it user readable. I want to ask for input through a web application and show the results by the graph.

Comment: In general stack overflow is better suited for more specific questions. Try something and you can find help when you are stuck. Questions about the general approach are often too broad to answer effectively.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin you can do better.

His question is simply that he has built and successfully deployed an AutoML model in GCP, now can this model be used on a 3rd Party platform like Streamlit - how can that endpoint be interacted with from streamlit?

I really wished I had the answers @ PUSHKARKUDLIKAR but please share as an answer where you have. Cheers.

Comment: So - I found this interesting article that may have the answers here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-custom-ama-app-using-vertexai-4788834fb766
repo: https://github.com/datasherlock/custom-genai-search-engine/tree/main

Apparently, you have to containerize the whole application and deploy from GCP's Container Registry.

We can work on this together.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you may have to build locally @ first, to at least test. I'd suggest a streamlit application. Also, you would need to understand how to Handle secrets and building with Cloud Run.

I have a tutorial that shows to achieve this with a Streamlit App, using a deployed Vertex AI' endpoint: https://dev.to/afrologicinsect/lets-build-your-first-ml-app-in-google-cloud-run-1ol2

Comment: The question explicitly asks not to do anything locally. If you really want to give this kind of answer ar least explain the path to follow (e.g. leveraging a vm or so on GCP)